# Rodeo will not import packages but Jupyter can

Tags: package, rodeo

I am not sure if this is an issue with Rode.
Rodeo can not find the packages that Jupyter can find and import.
When I run "py -m pip list", I get a list of packges.  The packge (specifically "Quandl" is there

I can import and use these packages just find using Jupyter.  when I try using Rodeo it tells me that package is not there.

Starting to get frustrating .

Is my path set incorrectly.  I like using Rodeo.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it doesnt' work, but I can use the following the import the packages using Rodeo installer:

```
import pip

pip.main(['install','quandl'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you install packages using pip, a popular package manager for Python modules.

```
import pip

pip.main(['install','nltk'])

from nltk import *
```